# Unable to run Application on Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to run my application in eclipse using Apache Tomcat7 however I keep getting the following errors. I have tried deleting the server and adding it back several times and cleaning the directory etc and it does not work. See details under.

[image: Eclipse Message]

**Server Settings**

[image]

**Eclipse Console Error:**

```
   Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.96
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 24 2019 13:00:10 UTC
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.96.0
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Development\Windows XP Share\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Development\Windows XP Share\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Development\Windows XP Share\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/lib/amd64;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Development\ora6i\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Development\oracle_xe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Development\ora6i\jdk\bin;C:\openSSH\bin; /cygdrive/c/Repositories;$HOME/bin;$GitoliteHome/bin;C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\eclipse-jee-2018-09-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 689 ms
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.96
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Development\Windows XP Share\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\xxxxxxxxx does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5326)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxxxxx]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxxxxx]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxxxxx]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxxxxx]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxxxxx]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxxxxx]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Oct 16, 2019 6:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: Is `xxxxxxx` the (masked) name of your web application?

Comment: Yes I masked the name of the web app

Comment: Is `Windows XP Share` a local directory?

Comment: Yes windows xp share is a local directory on the C drive

Comment: Application was ported from a machine that used tomcat 7. My environment uses tomcat 8.5 but I installed 7 on the same machine and run them separate. I can access tomcat 7 and 8 once the service is started and access their web page

Comment: So... you are all good, then? Or you are still having the problem?

Comment: The issue was resolved by moving the project to a new workspace

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base
>   C:\Development\Windows XP
>   Share\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\xxxxxxxxx
>
> **does not exist or is not a readable directory**

This means that the server cannot find the servlet so you need to check the @WebServlet annotaion for error, you can use @WebServlet("/xxxxxxxx")

or in your jsp, add

${requestScope.getContextPath()/xxxxxxx

Wish this was hepful